# App's download count in google play by my suggestion

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I'm looking for some information on the details shown in an app's page on the Google Play. I have a web page , where I have replaced link, which redirect the user to app in google play. Is it possible to know how users download app from google play by my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But you need integrate tracking sdk into app. For example, [appsflyer sdk](http://www.appsflyer.com/).